# Parse invalid XML C#

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, serialization

Here is the invalid xml response I need to parse with C#, 
I'm trying to create a class for the responses and have had little success.

```
<Response service=\"RouteService\">
<Head>OK</Head>
<Body>
    <RouteResponse mailno=\"070033764942\">
        <Route accept_time=\"2017-03-23 10:57:13\"\taccept_address=\"United States\"\tremark=\"For Sign Info, please see 'AWB Info &amp; POD' in our website\"\topcode=\"8000\"/>
        <Route accept_time=\"2017-03-23 10:52:10\"\taccept_address=\"United States\"\tremark=\"Have been signed(MS.TT),Thank you for using SF, and looking forward to serving you again\"\topcode=\"80\"/>
        <Route accept_time=\"2017-03-23 10:52:10\"\taccept_address=\"United States\"\tremark=\"Have been signed(MS.TT),Thank you for using SF, and looking forward to serving you again\"\topcode=\"80\"/>
        <Route accept_time=\"2017-03-23 10:46:37\"\taccept_address=\"SHENZHEN CITY\"\tremark=\"S.F. Express has picked up the shipment\"\topcode=\"50\"/>
        <Route accept_time=\"2017-03-23 10:46:37\"\taccept_address=\"SHENZHEN CITY\"\tremark=\"S.F. Express has picked up the shipment\"\topcode=\"50\"/>
    </RouteResponse>
</Body>
```

Comment: Replace all `\"` with `"` and all `\t` with `    `?

Comment: Fix the code that generated invalid xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to use the standard C# XML libraries to parse a non-legal XML file.

That won't work.  You need to make the file "valid" first.

SUGGESTION:

1. Read the XML text into a string.
2. Replace all `\"` with `"`.
3. Use the standard libraries to parse the "corrected" XML.

Comment: there does need to be spaces added where there is \t, for proper parsing.